# What `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` is used for?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, reindex, optimization

I am trying to understand better the indexer process and see it I can find a way to optimize it.

In particular, since it is the biggest table on my DB, I am focused on this table `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`:

- It contains association between products and their attribute values (all attributes or only some ? )
- Many records are the same the only difference is the storeview ( It think this could be changed to reduce the space on the table )
- I cannot find any point it the code ( except the reindex part ) where this table is actually used ( what is the purpose of this table, also given the fact there is a product_flat table ? )

Thanks